# Problems on alignment elements to the right without overlap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having a problem with the alignment of two "buttons" (links) on the right in bootstrap.

My goals are two:

1. To make them as right-aligned as possible.
2. To always have a small margin between them.

Although at first the separation between them is more or less correct and I can get them to be aligned to the right without an excessive margin of the last element on the right side, as I reduce the size of the page, both end up overlapping.

I've managed to prevent this from happening by putting mr-x, mr-sm-x,... classes on them, but I can see that it doesn't make any sense because in order for it to work more or less well, I have to put an excessive amount of classes on them. Something like:

```
ml-3 ml-sm-1 ml-md-1 mr-4 mr-sm-2 mr-md-2 mr-lg-1 mr-xl-0
```

And the result is not optimal either.

I have tried to make it work with *offset* classes, with *align-items-end* and with *justify-content-end*. Also with *float-right*, but I always have problems with margins and overlap.

Here are some images that show the problem and the example in jsfiddle

[image: Initially]

[image: If I reduce the width page the elements become to overlap]

[image: My goal is that the element are shown always like this]

[Example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oms02/7w9pqekz/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to use Bootstrap's [button groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/button-group/):

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar heading-title">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Título</span>
  </nav>
  <nav class="navbar row justify-content-end">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
      <a class="btn" href="#" role="button">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      </a> <a class="btn" href="#" role="button">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/398a52sn/)**

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot.